# memcpy-- kernel crash after memcpy

Tags: c, linux-kernel

i need help i am trying to use memcpy to copy a header at kernel space but the screen just goes black and it seems like it does not like my memcpy. pls somebody help me.

```
        remaining = ntohs(iphead->tot_len) - 20; //(remaining = total size of ip packet - size of meta header)
 while(remaining != 0) {
    currentHead = (struct iphdr *) pos; //save the first 'real' header
    if(currentHead == NULL)
        goto fail;
    nskb = dev_alloc_skb(ntohs(currentHead->tot_len) + MAC_LENGTH );
    if(nskb == NULL)
        goto fail; //We can't allocate that memory so we leave
    if(nskb->tail + MAC_LENGTH + ntohs(currentHead->tot_len) <= nskb->end){ 

        nskb->data = skb_put(nskb, (MAC_LENGTH + ntohs(currentHead->tot_len))); // allocated all the memory we need
        memcpy(nskb->data,(*skb)->mac_header, MAC_LENGTH); //Put the mac header in place
        nskb->mac_header = nskb->data; //Save the mac header location
        nskb->network_header = nskb->data + MAC_LENGTH; //Move the pointer to where the network header will be
        memcpy(nskb->network_header, pos, ntohs(currentHead->tot_len)); //save the ip + payload

        nskb->data = nskb->network_header;
```

Comment: As worded your question is not very clear, or reproducible. If I were you I would not just throw up code, but explain clearly and concisely what is going wrong. Provide code that we can compile and test, and explain what you saw, and what you expected. Also specify what OS you are working on, and in what programming environment you are working with too.

Comment: Does the call to `memcpy` ever return?  If so, what value does it return?  Since this is in a loop, does it fail on the first loop iteration or only when `remaining` is a certain value?

Comment: ok sorry about my unclearity, am running linux 2.6.32-30-generic what is happening is that the i compiled the code well no errors but when i upload it to the kernel with insmod deaggr.ko the screen goes black such that to get it back i must restart. in var/log/messages it says 31 m of stolen memory.graphics performance may suffer. what i am doing is am copying a mac header from an deaggregated packet (skbs bundled together) which is (*skb)->mac_header to on top of a single skb and then insert it back to the network stack. it fails on the loop but i commented out the loop still fails on memcpy

Comment: i dont know if there is anyway i could attach the code because stack overflow has a limited number of characters to take,so i can't upload the code because its long and it also has a .h file

Answer (score 0):

Is pos truly valid?  Which memcpy is giving you problems?  Is this the Linux kernel I assume?

Comment: unsigned char *pos = (*skb)->data - MAC_LENGTH; // pos points to start of mac header------------------(this is what pos is)-------yes it is a kernel issue. (this is the memcpy giving problem) memcpy(nskb->data,sb->mac_header, MAC_LENGTH);

Comment: Hello can any one please help me with the above code, i just want to know if i have assigned my pointers right because they are there ones that i think gives me problem

Comment: @docas would you care to elaborate in case other people run in to this same issue?  It is acceptable SO practice to write an answer to your own question and then accept that answer.  Remember we're all in here to help each other and to generate good references for solving problems that we all run in to in the future.  Thanks

Comment: i was referring to the wrong locations i was supposed to use & because i was using the value itself whereas i wanted the address location.